# BlueCove for Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth, bluecove

Does anybody know if Bluecove for Java works with Wiondows 7 32 bit? I have tried to connect a wiimote to my computer via bluetooth and it is unable to connect after I paired the device. I know that there has been issues with the x64 computers but it this also a problem with x86?

Comment: hi @user1506919 any updates on this question? did the answer below satisfied your query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works with Windows 7 32 bit. Download the latest bluecove snapshot and put it in your classpath. I have been using it for quite sometime